# How to solve this when many Threads can set on/off state on progressBar

Tags: android, multithreading, android-progressbar, greenrobot-eventbus

I have this `AppCompatActivity` that host a `ViewPager` containing 3 `Fragments` now in the `AppCompatActivity` `toolbar` I have this `ProgressBar` that each of the Fragment can turn on/off using the following calls:

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onShowProgressBar(OnRequestToShowProgressBarEvent onRequestToShowProgressBarEvent) {
    progressIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onHideProgressBar(OnRequestToHideProgressBarEvent onRequestToHideProgressBarEvent) {
    progressIndicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

The `Fragment` are doing work independently and when doing the work they can turn on the `ProgressBar` and turn it off when finished.

Now it occurred to me that this will fail since Frag_1 can turn on the `ProgressBar` and Frag_2 can turn it off and still the Frag_1 has not finished working and should have the `ProgressBar` on but now it´s off right.

How to solve this?

Comment: Was thinking using a stack like - all "show" go on the stack and all "hide" pop the stack and the ProgressBar is visible as long as the stack can pop

Comment: Instead, do the right thing, move the logic out of all three fragments and have a “presenter” in charge of all the work that only publishes the states when needed. E.g.: when all three are done, hide it, else, while there’s work, it’s visible. The logic belongs outside of the fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own Q I think this might work, following up on Marconcini comment I place the logic outside at where the `ProgressBar` live like this:

```
protected ProgressBar progressIndicator;
private final Stack<String> progressBarStack;


@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onShowProgressBar(OnRequestToShowProgressBarEvent onRequestToShowProgressBarEvent) {
    synchronized (progressBarStack) {
        progressBarStack.push("show");
        progressIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onHideProgressBar(OnRequestToHideProgressBarEvent onRequestToHideProgressBarEvent) {
    synchronized (progressBarStack) {
        progressBarStack.pop();
        if (progressBarStack.empty())
            progressIndicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Here the 3 Frags must promise to hold there end of the bargain to call `onHideProgressBar()` after they have called `onShowProgressBar()`

This seems to work but probably there is some cavities I haven't thought of.